# ls command error via SFTP in Linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell

i have the next code:

```
files=$(lftp -u mgtwrk35,Unix11! sftp://illin634<<EOF
cd some_dir
ls | tail -1
EOF)
```

why does the code above work, 
but if i add to the ls function -tr like:

```
ls -tr | tail -1
```

it doesn't work and gives me the next message:

```
ls: invalid option -- t
ls: invalid option -- r
```

Thanks in advance for the answer

Comment: `ls` in `lftp` doesn't support `-t` and `-s` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The `ls` in lftp is not the real thing. It's also named "ls" but does not support all the parameters you can find in the standard `ls`.

- `find` lets you recursively list files.
- `cls --sort=date` lets you sort by modification date.

I don't know how to combine the two. There's a [work-around mentioned by Nicolas Noble](http://www.mail-archive.com/lftp@uniyar.ac.ru/msg01702.html), which is to use `awk` to post-process the result of `find`.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain more about the way you mentioned above ?

Comment: find gives you "ls -r". It's then possible to do `find | whatever`, and `whatever` will be able to reorder those files based on some criteria, eg. looking at the value of `cls --sort=date`. I don't know about awk, so it would be hard to provide a working solution. Do you really need this?