# how to enter to the last created directory via SFTP connection in Linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sftp

hi as a continue to may previous question ([ls command error via SFTP in Linux shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434249/ls-command-error-via-sftp-in-linux-shell-script)) i have a question:
**How can i get the name (or enter) of the latest created directory via SFTP connection ?**

As i was told here the function **ls -tr | tail -1** option won't work here, as parameters as **-tr**  are not recognized in SFTP.

for example the script after SFTP connection:

```
cd temp_dir
?????????
```

assuming that the **temp_dir** containing several directories, i need to enter the last created directory in it (in order to download the files from it).
how can i do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While sftp use ssh, the better solution is to `ssh` to the server and :

```
cd $(ls -t | sed q)
```

Comment: hi, but i cant ssh within an sftp command, and to make an ssh connection i need to enter a password manually, and i need it to be automatic connection within a script, also i can't use key authentication, because those are company machines, and i have to use a password authentication (but i need it to be automatic, which i can't do in ssh command).

Answer (score 0):

Your previous question contains the essential fact that you use `lftp`; therewith using `cls` instead of `ls` will help.

```
cls -1t|sed -n 1s/^/cd\\ /p>/tmp/cd
source /tmp/cd
```

Beware, this uses the file `/tmp/cd` and is not suited for concurrent operation.